# How can I write my own plugin for Webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

I want to write a specialized plugin for WebStorm that can provide help for a custom framework, are there any tutorials on how to do that?

Answer (score 13):

There is no WebStorm specific guide available, [plug-ins are created exactly the same way as for IntelliJ IDEA](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment).

You are welcome to ask more specific questions in [the forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development).

Answer (score 2):

As @CrazyCoder says there is no specific official guide to write a Webstorm plugin. The reason is that all plugins are written in the same way, but you can decide for [which IDE it will be available](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html?search=Compatibility%20with%20Multiple%20Products#modules-specific-to-functionality).

I found [this post](https://medium.com/@andresdom/developing-an-intellij-webstorm-javascript-plugin-65416f9afea3) very helpful to start building a Webstorm plugin.