# Swapping quote types within selection in WebStorm

Tags: string, replace, webstorm, double-quotes, single-quotes

We have to adapt our existing code to new tslint rules and switch places of all double and single quotes, e.g. the following snippet

```
 this.errorMsg = errorBody 
     +"<hr/><a href='"
     +error.url+"' target='_blank'>HTTP "
     +error.status
     +" "
     +error.statusText
     +"</a>";
```

should look

```
this.errorMsg = errorBody
     +'<hr/><a href="'
     +error.url+'" target="_blank">HTTP '
     +error.status
     +' '
     +error.statusText
     +'</a>';
```

Do you have something special in your bag of tricks?

Something like that would be great:

[image]

Comment: No way to do it in one pass. Replace `'` with `&&##&&`, then all `"` with `'`, and then all `&&##&&` with `"`. You may  choose whatever instead of `&&##&&`.

Comment: Dear @WiktorStribiżew, is that a joke? :)

Comment: When I joke, I add :) I didn't.

Comment: I personally do not know any built-in functionality that will do it one one go. So Find & Replace sounds like possible way to go .. although dangerous. You could use `Quick Fix` menu (the light bulb icon --`Alt + Enter` on Windows/Linux) but 1) AFAIK it works on per string level (so would require at least 4 invocations for your sample) and most importantly 2) it does not switch them across -- it just replaces top level and escapes internal ones .. so `"<hr/><a href='"` would become `'<hr/><a href=\''` .. which is still not what you ask for

Comment: should I change to vi back :/ There was a plugin (https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) there,..

Comment: You may use Notepad++ safely and nicely. Do you want me to post a solution for NPP?

Comment: we use company-wide WebStorm, thank you!

Comment: Then use my first comment.

Comment: Looking for an efficient way to do that, thanks anyway,..

Comment: You should choose between 1) working inefficient way, 2) no "efficient" way at all.

Comment: yes, that's currently true but I wrote a regex-function, which does it now for me,..

Comment: Why don't you post it here then?

Comment: Because it is neither a WebStorm issue nor js-related, but something like that: `str.replace(/[\'\"]/g, function(sequence){
    return sequence === '"' ? "'" : '"';})`

Comment: See [*How can I write my own plugin for Webstorm?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045385/how-can-i-write-my-own-plugin-for-webstorm).

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew ! That's an hint,..